# Docker Sockets and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, sockets

I am trying to get this simple python3 code to run in docker using sockets, but I receive the following error. Can someone point me in the right direction. I am just trying to get it to work so i can integrate it into my broader project

```
File "registrar.py", line 29, in <module>
  with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Server

```
import socketserver
import json

list_of_nodes = []
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The request handler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """
    def handle(self):
        global list_of_nodes
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(json.loads(self.data))
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        list_of_nodes.append(json.loads(self.data))
        self.request.sendall(bytes(str(len(list_of_nodes)-1), 'utf-8'))
        print(list_of_nodes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 58333

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
```

Client

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import json


HOST, PORT = "localhost", 58333
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
dict_node = {'nVersion': 1,
             'nTime': time.time(),
             'addrMe': socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
             }

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    json_msg = json.dumps(dict_node)
    sock.sendall(bytes(json_msg, "utf-8"))

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")

print("Sent:     {}".format(json_msg))
print("Received: {}".format(json.loads(received)))
```

Comment: This means the TCPServer is not designed to be used with `with`

Comment: thx, it works fine locally in ubuntu and pycharm, i was just trying to test it in a docker container

Comment: Your docker container might have an older version of Python

Comment: yes, it's Python 3.4, thanks ive ammended the code